# Validate a password using regular expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a password that meets certain conditions like:

1. Has at least one upper case
2. At least one lower case
3. At least one number
4. One non alphanumeric character

I've already tried this:

```
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must have a minimun of {2}and maximum of {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
     [RegularExpression(@"^(?!.([A-Za-z0-9])\1{1})(?=.?[A-Z])(?=.?[a-z])(?=.?[0-9])(?=.?[#?!@$%^&-])$", ErrorMessage = "My error messaage in spanish lol")]
            public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

However, when i try a password like “Qwerty123.” it acts like some or none of the conditions where met as i get the error message. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You dont have a special character in your `Qwert123`

Comment: i do, i use a period at the end

Comment: Be aware that [password rules are bullshit](https://blog.codinghorror.com/password-rules-are-bullshit/); they make accounts less secure, not more.

Comment: The only rule I would enforce is **minimum** password length, make it at least 10 characters long. The rest of the rules is bull.

Comment: Walk the password, iterating over the string like `foreach (char c in pwString)` and then use methods like `char.IsDigit` to check. It'll be easier to read and maintain and likely more performant (not that that matters here)

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC already has a built-in validator that can do all those, why do you need to roll out your own?

```
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    
    manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
    {
        RequiredLength = 6,
        RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
        RequireDigit = true,
        RequireLowercase = true,
        RequireUppercase = true,
        MaxLength = 10
    };
```

You could customize the password validator by subclassing the PasswordValidator (or implement IIdentityValidator) and provide your own implementation.

Comment: Because i need the error message to be in spanish and not in english.

Comment: Please don’t add a silly max length, and consider 10-12 as a min length to encourage (and not discourage) pass phrases and auto-generated random passwords. To the OP as well..

Comment: @AnthonyOrtega for that you should use Localization, but a quick and dirty way would be to override PasswordValidator and provide your own error message.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use positive lookaheads with variable length `(?=.*<condition>)`, so the expression would look like this:
`^(?=.{10,20}$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[#?!@$%^&-]).*$`
where
`(?=.{10,20}$)` defines min and max length
`(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[#?!@$%^&-])` defines all chars required at least once

I guess your biggest mistake was using `.?`, wich would only allow one zero or one preceding character in the groups, but i'm not sure what `(?!.([A-Za-z0-9])\1{1})` is supposed to archive